# Is csrf protection required for extremely short lived cookies?

Tags: authentication, security, csrf

I have an app with token-based authentication .

for specific endpoint that serves an pdf file, it was ideal for me to authenticate via cookie.

so I creates a cookie with 1 second lifetime , just for the use of this endpoint:

```
    // Set one-time cookie only for this action
    Cookie.set("token", token, {
      secure: true,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000), // one second lifetime
    });
    
    // Open url
    const newTab = window.open(
      pdfURLForAuthenticatedUsers,
      "_blank"
    );
```

Do I need to implement csrf protection in this case? or it is safe enough ?...

thanks!

Comment: Is it acceptable if the user exploits all the permissions this token grants within that one second and not just the one granted by that specific URL? Could they maybe read *other* PDFs that you didn't intend? Could that token be used to trigger *any* action that is detrimental to the user?

Comment: No, this token is the user's access token. generally it used in AJAX  requests as an Authorization header. but here I want to put it in a cookie to make the PDF display and download compatible with all browsers (long story).

Comment: Then you probably need CSRF protection just as in any other case, because an outside actor might be able to trick users into taking actions with this token that they didn't intend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) But if I understood correctly, the attacker needs to make users click on an infected link, then steal the cookies. So can't I assume that users won't click on a link this second?